# How can I add a peer to a light client?

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, peers

I am hosting my own Geth Full-node which is setup to server light-clients and it has a static ip.

When I start my own light-client, can I specify it to use my full-node instead of wasting time on searching for new peers?

It would help me save time when starting a light client.